# Call Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan cmdlet with arbitrary parameters

Tags: azure, powershell

I want to call [Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/set-azurermappserviceplan?view=azurermps-6.13.0) with *arbitrary* parameters, the list of parameters is defined in runtime and is not set statically.

In other languages like Perl I would use Hash for this, but I get stuck here in Powershell even though I know that Powershell supports HashTables.

Following example does not work

```
$params = @{}

$params.add('-WorkerSize', 'Small');
$params.add('-NumberofWorkers', '2');

Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName 'RG1' -Name 'AppServicePlna1' $params
```

I get `Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan : Long running operation failed with status 'BadRequest'.` error from Azure.

Comment: Change `$params` to `@params` in the call to `Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan`.  Check out the [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) help for more details.

Comment: @boxdog, thanks! it helped

Comment: @boxdog You can post it as an answer.

Comment: @JoyWang. Done :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell does support what you are trying to do.  It is known as [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6).

In your case, you have a minor typo.  All you need to do is change the `$` to an `@` in this line:

`Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName 'RG1' -Name 'AppServicePlna1' $params`

So the working version looks like this:

`Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName 'RG1' -Name 'AppServicePlna1' @params`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with PowerShell per say.

Last time I checked you cannot pass 'Parameter key' for an Azure Module command.

Comment: Hi! It's was not even an issue. It was I didn't know how. Now I do.